# Regaining control of web browser control issue

Tags: wpf, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows form project(vs2010 - vb.net) were on a page load an url is loaded into a web browser control. The user then fills in around 6 pages of forms within the control. Once they get to the end of the forms then they click a button on the windows form to continue.

What this is meant to do is the following:

```
For Each dElement As HtmlElement In iqbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("p")
        If dElement.InnerText.Contains("(Saved Quotation Identifier ") Then
            rqid = dElement.InnerText.ToString
        End If
    Next
```

however once the button is clicked no elements are found? It is like the control has lost focus. I have tried .focus, .select, .bringtofront but no dice! Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the HTML of the Form? It'd be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to worry, the issue was that the html was in a frame which I forgot about, this fixed the issue as soon as I referenced the frame